# Why embed async in async?

Tags: f#

I read the following code from the book Expert f#,

1. Why the function `collectLinks` embeds `let! html = async { .... }` in the outer `async` block? How about just flat it by removing the inner async?
2. Same question for the function `waitForUrl` in `urlCollector` which has a `do! Async.StartChild (async {....}) |> Async.Ignore` in an outer `async` block. How about flat it?
3. How is the implementation comparing with the one implemented with block queue? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297096(v=vs.100).aspx Creating a block queue with 5, and en-queue the link to producer.

Code:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Net
open System.IO
open System.Threading
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let limit = 50
let linkPat = "href=\s*\"[^\"h]*(http://[^&\"]*)\""
let getLinks (txt:string) =
    [ for m in Regex.Matches(txt,linkPat)  -> m.Groups.Item(1).Value ]

// A type that helps limit the number of active web requests
type RequestGate(n:int) =
    let semaphore = new Semaphore(initialCount=n, maximumCount=n)
    member x.AsyncAcquire(?timeout) =
        async { let! ok = Async.AwaitWaitHandle(semaphore,
                                                ?millisecondsTimeout=timeout)
                if ok then
                   return
                     { new System.IDisposable with
                         member x.Dispose() =
                             semaphore.Release() |> ignore }
                else
                   return! failwith "couldn't acquire a semaphore" }

// Gate the number of active web requests
let webRequestGate = RequestGate(5)

// Fetch the URL, and post the results to the urlCollector.
let collectLinks (url:string) =
    async { // An Async web request with a global gate
            let! html =
                async { // Acquire an entry in the webRequestGate. Release
                        // it when 'holder' goes out of scope
                        use! holder = webRequestGate.AsyncAcquire()

                        let req = WebRequest.Create(url,Timeout=5)

                        // Wait for the WebResponse
                        use! response = req.AsyncGetResponse()

                        // Get the response stream
                        use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

                        // Read the response stream (note: a synchronous read)
                        return reader.ReadToEnd()  }

            // Compute the links, synchronously
            let links = getLinks html

            // Report, synchronously
            do printfn "finished reading %s, got %d links" url (List.length links)

            // We're done
            return links }

/// 'urlCollector' is a single agent that receives URLs as messages. It creates new
/// asynchronous tasks that post messages back to this object.
let urlCollector =
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun self ->

        // This is the main state of the urlCollector
        let rec waitForUrl (visited : Set<string>) =

           async { // Check the limit
                   if visited.Count < limit then

                       // Wait for a URL...
                       let! url = self.Receive()
                       if not (visited.Contains(url)) then
                           // Start off a new task for the new url. Each collects
                           // links and posts them back to the urlCollector.
                           do! Async.StartChild
                                   (async { let! links = collectLinks url
                                            for link in links do
                                               self.Post link }) |> Async.Ignore

                       // Recurse into the waiting state
                       return! waitForUrl(visited.Add(url)) }

        // This is the initial state.
        waitForUrl(Set.empty))
```

Comment: You're asking why the code that *you posted* use nested `async` blocks? Wouldn't you be the first person to answer that question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of one reason why `async` code would call another async block, which is that it lets you dispose of resources earlier - when the nested block completes. To demonstrate this, here is a little helper that prints a message when `Dispose` is called:

```
let printOnDispose text = 
  { new System.IDisposable with
      member x.Dispose() = printfn "%s" text }
```

The following uses nested `async` to do something in a nested block and then cleanup the local resources used in the nested block. Then it sleeps some more and cleans up resources used in the outer block:

```
async { 
  use bye = printOnDispose "bye from outer block"
  let! r = async {
    use bye = printOnDispose "bye from nested block"
    do! Async.Sleep(1000)
    return 1 }
  do! Async.Sleep(1000) }
|> Async.Start
```

Here, the "nested block" resources are disposed of after 1 second and the outer block resources are disposed of after 2 seconds.

There are other cases where nesting `async` is useful (like returning from an asynchronous block containing `try` .. `with`), but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: In addition to Tomas' answer, it's quite common in GUI programming to use Async.StartImmediate which will start the async workflow on the same thread as the UI thread. Then from within the workflow you would make other async calls (web requests, file access, etc etc) and be returned to the UI thread for safely updating the UI. So in my example the main async workflow would not be on a new thread/threadpool thread but on the the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and comments. What's the purpose the second nested `do! Async.StartChild(async{....})|> Async.Ignore` which doesn't have  any `use` or `use!` in the block?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : The key there is the call to `Async.StartChild` – this lets the nested workflow run _in parallel_ with the outer workflow, so that a page doesn't need to wait for all of its contained links to be collected in order to be considered finished. (The `do!` here corresponds to the `Async.Ignore`, not the `Async.StartChild`.)